# Joomla4 : how to set parameters in an extension?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I have developed a Joomla3 extension and I try to run in in Joomla4.1

In my XML file:

```
<extension version="3.1" type="plugin" group="content" method="upgrade">

<config>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="basic">
            <field name="webmasterid" type="text" default="" label="Enter webmasterid"/>
            <field name="password" type="password" default="" label="Enter Password"/>
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</config>
```

But I don't see any way from my /administrator/ panel where I can set these 2 params:
webmasterid, password

What is the correct way to have them displayed in /administrator/ panel ?

**(the plugin still works correctly, but I have to set these values directly in my plugin code)**

Comment: While it is on-topic to ask this Joomla programming question on Stack Overflow, I recommend that you post your Joomla programming questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange to reach an audience that has expertise specifically in the CMS.